# render is called before the asynchronous method has finished in react native

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await, render

hi everyone i am recently learning react native and i have a synchronization problem sending data from one screen to another screen.
I have the parent page (UserList) that wants to send its status to the child page (RecyclerViewPage) but the render is called before the data is available.

```
export default class UserList extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.state={
      comment_state: [],
      datetime: []      
    }
}
//getPost is a network call which gets and store the result in the state of the class  
  async getPost(){
    var sid=this.props.route.params.value_sid
    var did=this.props.route.params.value_did
    const utils=new Utils();
    const responseJson = await utils.getPost(sid,did)
    const comment = (responseJson?.posts ?? []).map((data) => data.comment)
    this.setState({comment_state:comment})
  console.log("now i change state with new value")
    }
  componentDidMount(){
this.getPost()
  } 
  render(){ 
  return(
    <RecyclerViewPage 
    comment={this.state.comment_state} 
    />
  )
}
}
```

and RecyclerViewPage code:

```
export default class RecyclerViewPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
console.log("i am in recyclerviewPage  : ",this.props.comment)
  }
render(){}
 }
```

I tried to put some logs and the result is:
Log: "i am in recyclerviewPage: []"
Log: "now i change state with new value"
It appears as if render () was called before the asynchronous getPost method has finished. how can i synchronize my code in order to get the data first and then send it to the RecyclerViewPage daughter schemata?

Answer (score 0):

See you can wait for the results and then show recyclerviewpage:
You can add a loader state while its being fetched:)

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

```
export default class UserList extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props); 
    this.state={
      comment_state: [],
      datetime: []      
    }
}
//getPost is a network call which gets and store the result in the state of the class  
  async getPost(){
    var sid=this.props.route.params.value_sid
    var did=this.props.route.params.value_did
    const utils=new Utils();
    const responseJson = await utils.getPost(sid,did)
    const comment = (responseJson?.posts ?? []).map((data) => data.comment)
    this.setState({comment_state:comment})
  console.log("now i change state with new value")
    }
  componentDidMount(){
this.getPost()
  } 
  render(){ 
  return(
{!!comment_state && <RecyclerViewPage 
    comment={this.state.comment_state} 
    /> }

{!comment_state && <Text> Please wait its loading </Text>}
    
  )
}
}
```